# What sort of tests are these and should they be written?

Tags: c#, testing

We have recently begun discussions around testing. One of the type of tests we would like are some sort of functional or acceptance tests. The hope is to cut down on wasteful dev and to have some soft of living documentation that is also self validating. The example we came up with as a proof of concept was to build out a http client, we chose this because it can get very complex very quickly and if you are not careful you could end up developing for days adding in little edge case handlers etc.

With this in mind we sat down and create a list of functionality that would cover exactly what we need and no more. When you look at this "Spec" it does not include things like interface abstraction or configuration, in fact a nice fluent interface would knock most of the items off the list.

So now the prompt is blinking at me and I don't know what to write. I have done unit testing before but we found that these were lacking for bigger objects or for testing in a more cohesive fashion were you create some sort of scenario and verify it passes. Don't mistake this as a knock against unit testing, I imagine it has more to do with us rather than with unit testing. Anyhoo

Off the top of my head I am thinking the following.

- Write a scenario, an example would be something like the following:

  ```
  Create a new http request. 
  This request should should be a GET request.
  It should have no body.
  It should have reasonable defaults already defined.
  ```
- Implement the scenario:

  ```
  var request = 
  new httpRequest().UsingMethod(HttpMethods.Get)
                   .WithDefaultHeaders();
  ```

I have concerns about this though. On the one hand it works perfect. I have satisfied the scenario and I can add more scenarios to feel out other requirements. On the other hand I would normally develop out the whole thing first and then test so it feels like I am loosing control of the features architecture.

**What I am trying to find out is this:**

- Is this type of testing normal, do people use it, does it have a name?
- Am I on the right path or could this end with me making massive architecture assumptions assumptions?
- Where does architecture fit in when doing this sort of testing or speccing. Its nice to have a definition of done, like above (spec is fulfilled) but somewhere along the line some sort of architecting has to be done right?

Finally. I want to keep this tool agnostic. We are using C# and xUnit and really don't want to add in any more complexity while we figure out the baseline.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  Besides if it works perfect what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Ramhound - It appears to be in the title.  It sounds like the OP is looking for the name of this type of test and whether it's a useful type of test to run.

Comment: @Bobson - The question should be within the body of the question.  Besides the question "should they be written" depends on the project's requirements.

Comment: Edited for clarity, the questions are at the bottom. It might be one question or 3. Due to my lack of knowledge in this domain I thought it best to ask the three and let the community decide if they are all part of the same question.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a component test to me. One thing to think about with the HTTP requests, dont just look for an OK response, but also do a quick content check too. If your expecting well formed HTML back maybe look for a unique word or phrase that appears on your static error page, or if your expecting JSON or XML consider a proper response would look like verses an error.

Comment: I did not downvote you. I upvoted you to balance it out as I have had to edit for clarity and it would be unfair to leave you on minus one. I wish people had to comment when downvoting.